# Method Overloading in Objective-C - not used for init?

Tags: objective-c, operator-overloading

I have just started programming in Objective-C, I understand it only partially supports method overloading due to the way the method names are generated (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286312/method-overloading-in-objective-c)).

However, my question is why I have never seen it used in any examples. The code below seems to work fine, but any sort of example I have seen, the second init would be named `initWithServerName` or something like that, instead of taking advantage of the overloading.

```
-(id) init {
    self = [super init];
    return self;
}

// usually this would be called initWithName or something? but to me it 
// seems easier this way because it reminds me of method overloading from C#.
-(id) init: (NSString*)newServerName {
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {      
        serverName = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:newServerName];
    }
    return self;
}
```

What is the reason for this? Does it cause problems in sub-classes to name methods this way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unlike Algol-style languages like C#, Objective-C's syntax is specifically designed for literate method names. `init:` tells me nothing about the method parameter. Is the receiver initing the thing I'm passing? No. It's using the argument in some way, so we use a descriptive name like `initWithFormat:` to specify that the argument is a format string.

Also, Objective-C does not have method overloading at all. Period. A single selector for a given class can only have one type signature. The only way to change behavior based on an argument's class is to have a method take a generic type that could include many different classes (like `id` or `NSObject*`), ask the argument for its class and do different things depending on the result of that query.

Comment: +1 for "Objective-C does not have method overloading at all. Period."

Answer (score 3):

That's not the same method. In objective-C a selector named `init` is different than one named `init:`. The colon is part of the selector name.

Also, init is overridden fairly often, you just have the wrong method.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from jer's answer, it also does not allow you to specify multiple ways to initialise an instance. For example, NSString has `initWithString:`, `initWithFormat:`, etc.