# Is method overloading not possible

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Method overloading in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286312/method-overloading-in-objective-c)

Is method overloading not possible.
I have two functions with the same name.
When declared like the below i'm etting errors.

```
-(RS232Msg*)CreateMessage:(REMOTE_MESSAGE_ID) nMessageNumber;
-(RS232Msg*)CreateMessage:(const uint8_t*) szMessageName;
```

when declared `-(RS232Msg*)CreateMessage:(const uint8_t*) szMessageName;` i'm not getting any errors.
I also have two functions as the same name with different return type and argument.But its working fine and there is no error in its declaration.
Why is it so?

Comment: the type of parameter i'm passing is different.Why is the error.

Comment: because method overloading is not supported :) The reason is that parameter types is not a part of method signature in objective-c. Only their names matter.

Comment: @Vladimir & Itai:Thanks for explaining about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, method overloading is not possible in C, and therefore not possible in Objective-C (since Objective-C is a superset of C). If you'd like to use those two methods, you'll have to change their names. I would suggest the following:

```
- (RS232Msg *)createMessageWithMessageID:(REMOTE_MESSAGE_ID)nMessageNumber;
- (RS232Msg *)createMessageWithName:(const uint8_t*)szMessageName;
```

Comment: That's not changing their type signatures, that's changing their names. That's the whole point - having different type signatures with the same name isn't supported.

Comment: @Sherm Yeesh, sorry for the glaring mistake. You're right! Fixed.

Comment: No worries - it's a good answer despite that, and I don't give down votes for typos. :-)